# iOS launching background app on startup

Tags: ios, startup

Is it possible to start up an app when a iOS device starts up, or is there some other mechanism to wake an app perhaps with a push notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you're making the app for the App Store. If you're making an app for jailbroken devices, then you can create a launch daemon just like you would on Mac OS X.